# Storing data as numbers vs string values in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

I have a few different data which I want to store in a DB. One of them is rank (military). Since all the ranks go from bottom to top, would it be a better practice to store them in the db as numbers and then display them using their actual names on the front end? Then I would just have a single table which contained the equivalencies between the numbers and names and I could reference that before displaying.

Am I thinking about this the right way?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's a standard way of doing things, although IMO the actual values used to determine order of the rank should be separate from the values associated with the rank `[rank_id, rank_description, rank_order]`

Comment: Can you elaborate on that please? I'm still brushing back up on SQL.

Comment: `rank_id` is any old unique arbitrary number or an autonumber used to id the rank, `rank_order` is the number that indicates superiority; 1=Commander in Chief .. 99=REMF

Comment: Ah I understand, thank you!

For education's sake, why is that preferable?

Comment: Because if you add/edit/remove a new rank you only need to update a few rows in the "id" table to change the order as opposed to having to update every single row in the other table.

Comment: Oh duh. I was tunnelvisioned; this organization will not change it's ranks. But in the unlikely event, that is ideal. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's a common question in database, if you want to have your data [normalized vs denormalized](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/Should-I-Normalize-My-Database.htm).

Traditionally, as you say, it is good to have that stored as a number, so that if at some stage you want to correct a typo, or edit a name, you only have to do that in one simple place.

But sometimes, either because you are using a database mapping software like Hibernate and you want to make the developer's life easier so that you don't have to apply joins, or in the unlikely case that you have a BigData project where you can't afford to have a join of millions and millions of records, you may want to have that in one single table.